# 色情報にアルファ値を持たせられる動画フォーマットはありますか？

Tags: 動画

動画素材投稿サイトを作ろうと考えていると、各ピクセルの色情報にアルファ値を持たせれば合成に便利なので欲しくなりました。

しかし私が知る限り mp4 など有名どころの圧縮済み動画フォーマットは透明ピクセルを扱えません (APNG とアニメーション GIF を除く)。非圧縮の AVI や Flash を使う FLV では透過情報を扱えるようですが、できれば圧縮されている汎用的なフォーマットであって欲しいです。

アルファ値を扱える圧縮動画フォーマットは知られているのでしょうか？　あるいは、透過情報があると何かしら圧縮や再生などに不都合があるのでしょうか。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> アルファ値を扱える圧縮動画フォーマットは知られているのでしょうか？

プロ（～セミプロ）向けの動画編集ソフトでは、アルファチャネル付き動画フォーマットを扱えるものがあります。動画ファイル／動画コーデック自身でアルファチャネルを扱えるものや、アルファチャネルサポートあり静止画連番ファイルなどが主に使われます。一般にはあまり馴染みのないファイル形式が並んでいるかと思いますが、いずれも動画編集用途の中間コーデック(Intermediate codec)に区分される、高画質／低圧縮率な動画フォーマット（一部は連番静止画）になります。

https://www.rocketstock.com/blog/video-codecs-and-image-sequences-with-alpha-channels/ より引用：

> Video Codecs and Image Formats with Alpha Channels
>
> - Apple Animation
> - Apple ProRes 4444
> - Avid DNxHD
> - Avid DNxHR
> - Avid Meridien
> - Cineon
> - DPX
> - GoPro Cineform
> - Maya IFF
> - OpenEXR Sequence With Alpha
> - PNG Sequence With Alpha
> - Targa
> - TIFF

---

> 透過情報があると何かしら圧縮や再生などに不都合があるのでしょうか。

動画ファイル単体再生時には、アルファチャネルは利用されないのが一般的かと思います（背景が透けて見える動画プレイヤが欲しい人はあまり居ないでしょう）。

アルファチャネルを利用するとしたら、重ね合わせを前提とした素材動画クリップになるでしょうが、このときアルファチャネル情報＝オブジェクト領域／透過領域の区別は厳密に行われることが期待されます。アルファチャネルは可逆(Lossless)圧縮を行うことが望ましいため、データ圧縮の観点からはどうしても不利（圧縮しずらいためデータが肥大化）します。

Answer (score 0):

動画のフォーマットではなく、コーデックの問題のようです。
[アルファチャンネル付きの動画の拡張子って何...](https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q13197523813)

> その拡張子だからアルファをサポートしている、というわけではありません。ビデオコーデックが問題となります。

[【AviUtl】透明度付動画（RGBA）を出力･読み込みする方法【アルファチャンネル】](http://aviutl.info/rgba/)

> 透明度（アルファチェンネル付）の動画（.avi）を出力する方法についてです。
>   1.メニューの「プラグイン出力」→「拡張編集AVI/BMP出力（RGBA）」をクリックします
>   2.「ビデオ圧縮」を開く
>   3.「RGBA(32bit)」（非圧縮）もしくは「RGBAに対応している可逆圧縮コーデック」を選択します
>   ※RGBAに対応している可逆圧縮コーデックは「Ut Video Codec」「Lagarith」の2種類だけだと思うので、この2つを入れてないなら以下記事にて導入方法や使い方について紹介しているので参考にしてみて下さい。
>   （ちなみに、これらの可逆圧縮コーデックでエンコードする際は、「設定」から「RGBA」に設定する必要があります）
>   5.元の画面に戻って、出力ファイル名を入力して「保存」を押してエンコードします
>   6.エンコ完了

[アルファチャンネルとマットについて](https://helpx.adobe.com/jp/after-effects/using/alpha-channels-masks-mattes.html)

> Adobe Photoshop、ElectricImage、FLV、TGA、TIFF、EPS、PDF、Adobe Illustrator など、多くのファイル形式でアルファチャンネルを含むことができます。「数百万色＋」の色深度で保存された AVI や QuickTime 形式も、これらのコンテナに格納されている画像の生成に使用されたコーデック（エンコーダー）によっては、アルファチャンネルを含むことができます。After Effects は、Adobe Illustrator、EPS、および PDF ファイルの空白部分を自動的にアルファチャンネルに変換します。

Comment: 訂正ありがとうございます。新情報は可逆圧縮のAVIでしょうか。再生時の効率を考えるとMPEGのような圧縮方法であって欲しいですが、非可逆圧縮とアルファ値は相性悪いのですかね……。

Comment: 静止画だとこんなのもあるようです。[Webp - Wikipedia](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebP) 「JPEGとは異なり、非可逆圧縮でもアルファチャンネルを扱える。」